# Nginx common IP whitelist for all subdomains

Tags: nginx

If I have a number of virtual hosts in the `sites-enabled` folder, how can I have a common whitelist for all of them?

Aka each one has this block

```
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    allow 192.168.0.0/16;
    allow x.x.x.x;
    deny all;
```

How can I have that apply to all the virtual hosts by default, instead of having to write it for every subdomain?

Comment: You may also put your global restrictions in the `http` section of the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [include](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include)

eg put the following text in the file /etc/nginx/shared-configs/whitelist.conf

```
allow 127.0.0.1;
allow 192.168.0.0/16;
allow x.x.x.x;
deny all;
```

in the file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site1.conf

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  include /etc/nginx/shared-configs/whitelist.conf;
}
```

in the file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site2.conf

```
server {
  server_name site2.example.com;
  include /etc/nginx/shared-configs/whitelist.conf;
}
```